# Why can't you pass strings from contract to contract?

Tags: solidity

When calling trying to pass a string from contract to contract, I get an error. in getName with error. I'm aware you cannot pass strings but what is the reason?

> Return argument type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitly
>   convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string
>   memory. return toBeCalled.getName();

```
pragma solidity ^0.1.0;

contract ToContract{
    FromContract fromContract = new FromContract();

    function getName() constant returns (string) {
        return fromContract.getName();
    }

}

contract FromContract{
    string name = 'dapp';

    function getName() constant return(string){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this link  - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/contract-reading-a-string-returned-by-another-contract/3788#3788 - It explains why dynamic type size cannot be accessed by other contract.

Answer (score 1):

In solidity a string "Hey" is internally stored as ["H","e","y"] which is a dynamic array. As of now it has no support to pass dynamic arrays. you can try to work around this by passing the string as a part of an object.